# How to print multiple lines of text with enters after them?

Tags: python, string

I wanted to make a simple and basic game but I find I have to write way too many `print` commands. How can I write a big chunk of text in one command?

Let's say I wanted to print this:

```
line one    
line two    
line three    
line four    
line five
```

I would have to do:

```
print("line one")    
print("line two")    
print("line three")    
print("line four")    
print("line five")
```

I feel like writing those five commands took me way too long. I have searched and found this command but it didn't turn out as expected:

```
print("line one", \    
      "line two", \    
      "line three", \    
      "line four", \    
      "line five")
```

That command gives the following output:

```
"line one line two line three line four line five"
```

The command doesn't work as I wanted it to unless I am doing something terribly wrong! How do I get the expected output without that five commands?

Comment: @Plouff: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I think it's because that RedX submitted his edit while you were editing, then your edit *rollbacked* his edit. And I've edited again.

Comment: @KevinGuan: race conditions are evil!

Answer (score 3):

You also need to print the newline characters then. So either

```
print("line one\nline two\nline three")
```

Or something a bit more advanced but more clear:

```
print("\n".join(["line one", "line two", "line three"]))
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's Python 3, you can use

```
print(thing1, thing2, thingN, sep='\n')
```

Also, `\` is only a syntactic marker for the compiler that the current line continues onto the next line. It does not affect any of the actual code; it just lets you adhere to a character-per-line limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "\n" characters.
`print("a\nb")` produces:

```
a
b
```

For more complicated strings use:

```
s1="line 1"
s2="line 2"
s3="line 3"

print('\n'.join([s1, s2, s3]))
```

See result here:
https://repl.it/CChr/0

Comment: Hello all! Thank you for your answers! Will any of these answers work with a delay between each line? I 'import time' then I would put 'time.sleep()' between sentences to delay them.

Comment: @Sirian: that's an additional requirement you failed to mention in the question.

Comment: @Sirian: if you need to delay prints, use a loop and print from a list of strings instead. You can create a list from one long string with newlines with `str.splitlines()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry about that. I will try mention all needed information in my question next time. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you could use the multiline string

```
print("""line one
line two
line three""")
```

Comment: It would produce extra whitespaces!

Answer (score -1):

### Advanced print_function

You can use print function from **future** module, as below:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print('line 1','line 2','line 3', sep='\n')
```

This will print

> ```
> line 1
> line 2
> line 3
> ```

This is advanced print method

You can use other separation characters. also can use more extra parameters. You can read more on this from here: [https://docs.python.org/2/library/**future**.html#module-**future**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html#module-__future__)

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​1. `__future__.print_function` is just the `print()` function in Python 3, and  I'm sure that OP is using Python 3 so he doesn't need to import that. 2. This way has already been mentioned in [James's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36444036/5299236), so your answer is useless and I'd suggest delete it.

Comment: @kevin guan, thanks for your comment. If he use python 3 then its ok. But what if he use python 2?